# In Emacs org-mode, is there a way to auto-link to files?

Tags: emacs

So I'm playing around with spacemacs, considering a switch from vim. In Vim, my favorite plugin (one I can't live without) is vim-notes. Vim-notes has a neat feature where, if you you're writing a note, and type the name of another note, it automatically highlights it as a link. Then you can follow that link to go to the other note. Is something like this possible with emacs org mode?

Comment: [This](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-wikinodes.html) is similar to what you want. I personally use orgmode's builtin create link, radio links, etc.

Comment: That's super similar to what I'm looking for. Except I'm looking for plain-language highlighting, like if I have a file called "~/Notes/Henry James.txt", then typing "Henry James" in org mode should link to the file. I guess if nothing like that exists I can try to create it based on that camel case plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly plain text but adding a link like this enable you too open any file

`[[file:test.org][any text or file name here]]`

will make a hyper link to the file `test.org` in the current directory.

Comment: this isn't the same, so if you have a notes file that has "other note" then created a file "other note.org" , when you open the first file you won't have "other note" as a link and you have to edit it and any other file that include "other note" to link to the file.